# Executing cp Excluding Files from Bash Script

Tags: command-line, bash, 20.04, scripts

I am currently writing a bash script to automate a task for my research, i.e., procedurally creating multiple scripts that will be sent to a cluster.

My bash script is composed of a copy operation that will copy all the *files* to some folder with a name generated with a procedure, except this one file. I know how to do this manually, but within the bash script it does not seem to work:

```
#!bin/sh

i=0
var=""

while [ $i -lt 6 ]
do
   i=$(( $i+1 ))
   
   var="NameOfFolder${i}"
   mkdir "${var}"
   cp !(fileName) "${var}"
done
```

The problem I am having is that the parentheses in `cp` command are being interpreted differently.

The error I get is:

```
Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "done")
```

When I remove the line in which the `cp` command is given the script runs, so the problem is in that line. I have already tried:

```
#!bin/sh

i=0
var=""

while [ $i -lt 6 ]
do
   i=$(( $i+1 ))
   
   var="NameOfFolder${i}"
   mkdir "${var}"
   cp !((fileName)) "${var}"
done
```

and

```
#!bin/sh

i=0
var=""

while [ $i -lt 6 ]
do
   i=$(( $i+1 ))
   
   var="NameOfFolder${i}"
   mkdir "${var}"
   cp ( !(fileName) ) "${var}"
done
```

Without any success.

### Question

What is the proper way to introduce the commands in parentheses without the bash script interpreting them as "programming" operators?

Comment: `!()` is an extended pattern matching operator used by bash extglob. If you switch to `#!/bin/bash` and add `shopt -s extglob` your first example will work

Comment: it should be `mkdir` and instead of `i=$((i+1))` you can just type `((i++))` ... there is no reason to set the `var` two time...

Comment: Sorry, did not notice the ```mkdir``` typo in the post; just fixed it. Even if I change to the ```#! bin/bash``` and add the ```shopt -s extglob``` it still displays the same error.

Comment: `#!/bin/bash` ...

Comment: Still get the same error. :-/

Comment: does the fileName exists?

Comment: Yes, even with pattern searching it fails. Actually, it says ```shopt not found```, tried installing it, but no success...maybe a sudo???

Comment: I guess I can just copy everything and then use an ```rm``` command, but it would be a waste of memory if the file is too large.

Comment: I think it is easier with `rsync`, Replace `cp ( !(fileName) ) "${var}"` with the command line  `rsync --exclude="$filename" "${var}"` or something similar. The `--exclude` option of `rsync` makes things easy to manage.

Comment: Thanks @sudodus, the command that worked was: ```rsync * --exclude $fileName "./${var}"```, thanks a lot. Please answer the question, this might help others. Although I am still curious as to why ```shopt``` does not come with my Ubuntu 20.04 Linux distribution(!?)

Comment: `shopt` is a builtin bash command try `type shopt`

Comment: No luck either, still says ```shopt: not found```... puzzled.

Comment: Since shopt is not found, I don't think you are using Bash. Your script calls `/bin/sh` which is probably (a symlink to) the dash shell. Dash has no shopt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *brace expansion* to create a range of folders (you will also need to exclude the folders themself)

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob

for i in folder_{1..6}; do
    mkdir -p "$i" && \
    cp -t "$i" -- !(filename|${i%_*}_*)
done
```

Comment: Still get the error message: ```shopt: not found```,  even with the  ```type shopt``` directive.

Comment: what does `realpath /proc/$$/exe` say?

Comment: It says ```/usr/bin/dash```

Comment: [make bash my default shell](https://superuser.com/questions/46748/how-do-i-make-bash-my-default-shell-on-ubuntu)

Comment: Followed the advice and still says that ```/bin/bash``` is the default, so I hit enter (or type it in). I run again the  ```realpath /proc/$$/exe``` command and it throws the same message: ```/usr/bin/dash```.

Comment: logout and in again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119820/discussion-between-agescovar-and-bac0n).

Comment: Ok, just needed to run ```exec bash``` and then ```source ~/.bashrc``` to change from ```dash``` to ```bash```; just learned this. Otherwise your solution works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **`rsync`** as an alternative to the construct with `cp`: replace for example

```
cp ( !(fileName) ) "${var}"
```

with

```
rsync --exclude="$fileName" * "./${var}"
```

The `--exclude` option of `rsync` makes things easy to manage.

Comment: I like your solution, works better when remote copying than regular ```cp```.

Answer (score 0):

#### Hello, welcome to Askubuntu!

Try this:

#### Where:

1. `find` - a tool to (from man) "search for files in a directory hierarchy"
2. `.` is the folder/directory you want to include (all sub-directories & sub-files under this one will be searched)
3. `-name *.ext` - this is the extension (the ending .name of the file)
4. `-type f` is a type file.
5. `-exec strings {} path/to/this/copiedfiles \;` -  this one is executing the command `cp` on `file 1`,`file 1`..., all up to `last file found` to path/to/this/copiedfiles

#### So, for example:

Copy all files ending with ".odt" in the folder /home/bob/docs/ (including all the sub-files in sub-directories under **docs/**) to the directory /home/bob/backups/odt/:

`find /home/bob/docs/ -name "*.odt" -type f -exec cp {} /home/bob/backups/odt/{}.backup \;`

Comment: As usual - you reading this message; (first of all, I hope you are fine, and have a great,  corona-free year!)  -  I want to (however possible - in any way) improve my answers, so any feedback/edit/critic is well appreciated! (Does not need to sound nice - We are here to improve) Have it Great,  //Wishes from Sweden!